# Is Validation Data involved in Training using Keras Fit?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I ran the following `model.fit()` function,

```
history = model.fit(x=train1,
                y=labels,
                validation_data=(df.iloc[:,:-1], df.iloc[:,-1]),
                batch_size=32,
                verbose=1,epochs=100)
```

Where `train1.shape=(2889, 84)` and `df.iloc[:,:-1].shape= (759371, 119)`

When I run this, I get the following `ValueError` after just Epoch 1/100:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 84), found shape=(None, 119)
```

Why should this error matter so early on and halt the program--since we're still in the training state where the model is being presumably trained only on the training set not the test/validation set?

Answer (score 0):

Your model is evaluated using the validation data **after every epoch**. So, after the first epoch, the validation occurs, but your validation data does not have the proper shape. This is why you are getting this error.

So, try applying the same preprocessing functions to your validation data as you did to your training data so that they have the same shapes and your problem would be fixed.